# MySQL 'group by' with 'left join' throws away some entries

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I have a query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT 
    orders.order_id,
    items.item_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(graphics.graphic_id) AS graphic_ids
FROM orders orders 
    LEFT JOIN order_items items ON orders.order_id = items.order_id 
    LEFT JOIN order_graphics graphics on graphics.item_id = items.item_id
WHERE // etc
GROUP BY items.item_id
```

Orders can have zero or more items, and items can have zero or more graphics.  The goal is to get all orders matching the WHERE condition, itemize them by order item, and list the graphics on each order item, like so:

```
// ideal
+----------+---------+---------------+    
| order_id | item_id | graphic_ids   |
+----------+---------+---------------+
|     3097 |  NULL   | NULL          |
|     3098 |  NULL   | NULL          |
|     3099 |  NULL   | NULL          |
|     3100 |  112437 | NULL          |
|     3101 |  112677 | 127003        |
|     3102 |  112948 | 127314        |
|     3102 |  112949 | 127315        |
|     3102 |  112950 | 127316        |
|     3103 |  122807 | 138005,138006 |
+----------+---------+---------------+
```

However, the GROUP BY / GROUP_CONCAT clauses mean that all orders with zero items are grouped under NULL:

```
// reality
+----------+---------+---------------+
|     3097 |  NULL   | NULL          |
|     3100 |  112437 | NULL          |
|     3101 |  112677 | 127003        |
|     3102 |  112948 | 127314        |
|     3102 |  112949 | 127315        |
|     3102 |  112950 | 127316        |
|     3103 |  122807 | 138005,138006 |
+----------+---------+---------------+
```

Is there a good way to `group by` `item_id while still listing out all orders with no items on them?

Comment: If you include both columns in the `GROUP BY`, you should get the correct result, no?  `GROUP BY orders.order_id, items.item_id`.  MySQL's default behavior (different from most other RDBMS) is to permit columns in `SELECT` not also in `GROUP BY`, with sometimes indeterminate or confusing results.

Comment: Nice!  I had no idea that it was possible to have two GROUP BYs.  I guess it makes perfect sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Ideally, _all_ columns which appear in the SELECT or are used in calculation that are not part of an aggregate (`COUNT(),SUM(),MAX(),GROUP_CONCAT()` etc...) belong in the `GROUP BY` for predictable results. Sometimes it's tricky to achieve though.

Comment: Interesting. It sounds like overkill if the query is selecting dozens of columns, but I will keep that in mind.

Comment: It has to do with how aggregate functions are applied. If all columns are not grouped in `GROUP BY`, MySQL has to _guess_ at what values you want for the ungrouped columns. Often it picks the _first_ value that matches the group, and that may be what you want, and that is often fine when grouping over a single table with many similar rows, but causes  problems when working over joins.

Comment: In most other RDBMS, the query you started with would actually not even compile, since `order_id` was ungrouped.

Comment: So is that the case whenever I am performing a `JOIN`, or whenever I have at least one `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Whenever you have a `GROUP BY`, not just when joining. There are cases where MySQL will give you the intended result unambiguously, but more often than not it is ambiguous. Besides that (and we see it quite often here) if you get in the habit of not filling out the whole group by, when the time comes that you have to work with a database other than MySQL, you'll have to relearn a lot of how aggregate functions actually work.

Comment: I'd like to learn more, so I'm bringing this over to a new question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386750/why-is-it-not-sufficient-to-group-by-a-primary-key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have every column that isn't an aggregate calculation in your `group by` clause:

```
SELECT 
    orders.order_id,
    items.item_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(graphics.graphic_id) AS graphic_ids
FROM orders orders 
    LEFT JOIN order_items items ON orders.order_id = items.order_id 
    LEFT JOIN order_graphics graphics on graphics.item_id = items.item_id
WHERE // etc
GROUP BY orders.order_id, items.item_id
```