# Why is it not sufficient to group by a primary key?

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate

Suppose I have a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    items.item_id,
    items.name
    GROUP_CONCAT(graphics.graphic_id) AS graphic_ids
FROM order_items items
    LEFT JOIN order_graphics graphics ON graphics.item_id = items.item_id
WHERE // etc
GROUP BY items.item_id
```

As I understand it, the proper thing to do is to include every unaggregated column in the `GROUP_BY` like so:

```
GROUP BY items.item_id, items.name
```

This is to prevent records from being lost because MySQL doesn't know how to group them.  However, I'm not keen on writing a query with dozens of selected columns and having to keep all of those matched up to a `GROUP BY`.

My question is, why is grouping by the primary key `items.item_id` not sufficient?  Sure, technically MySQL is not told explicitly what to do with ungrouped columns, but I know there will never be more records than there are primary keys, so none will get lost.

I am new to MySQL and learning as I go from, to be honest, not the cleanest legacy code, but I am trying to get the whole picture.  So are there cases I am missing where records could be lost, or am I misunderstanding the reasons behind this practice?

(continued from: [MySQL 'group by' with 'left join' throws away some entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365844/mysql-group-by-with-left-join-throws-away-some-entries?noredirect=1#comment41425505_26365844))

Comment: The SQL standard defines the 'list all non-aggregate columns in the GROUP BY clause' requirement.  MySQL allows you to avoid that on occasion, but it isn't always obvious (to me, not a heavy MySQL user) what MySQL does when you don't spell it out. Newer versions of the SQL standard may have changed the rules.  Originally (SQL-86), the standard did not have primary keys — they were added in SQL-92, AFAICR (but it might have been in SQL-89).

Comment: For all rows within the items table, grouping by the PK is sufficient. As I understand it, some RDBMSs require that GROUP BY operates upon all non-aggregated columns referenced in the SELECT, but as you've spotted, this isn't strictly necessary - and MySQL allows you to deviate from this requirement. That said, it is considered good practice by some.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Postgres allows you to just group by PK and enforces that the ommitted columns are functionally dependent on grouped by columns. MySQL doesn't enforce it yet [but looks like finally it will](http://rpbouman.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/mysql-575-group-by-respects-functional.html) The linked article indicates this is permissible under SQL99.

Comment: @MartinSmith: thanks for the information.  The article makes interesting reading.